# Changing default apache web directories

Tags: apache-http-server

How to point `someaddress.lan` to default apache page and `www.someaddress.lan` to `/var/www/wordpress/`? Should I modify this file */etc/apache2/sites-available/default/etc/apache2/sites-available/default* or place some symlinks in default apache dir? What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to use separate [virtualhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) for each one of them. The exact method would depend on your distribution - debian uses a slightly different workflow.

Ubuntu has a nice guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html) but i'll simplify it a little based off [here](http://www.tequilafish.com/2007/08/02/apache-virtualhost-on-ubuntu/)

You need to create two files in /etc/apache2/sites-available

The names can be arbitrary but someaddress.lan and www.someaddress.lan would work

To do this, nano someaddress.lan

paste in the following

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName someaddress.lan
  DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

for the other file nano www.someaddress.lan

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.someaddress.lan
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
</VirtualHost
```

run `a2ensite someaddress.lan` and `a2ensite www.someaddress.lan`

and restart apache you should be good

Comment: I use ubuntu dist

Comment: @RCola: Ubuntu is based on Debian, and thus inherits more or less all its workflows. *EDIT:* I skip the rest of my Debian/Ubuntu centric comment since the answer was simultaneously updated with the same info :-) .

Comment: Yes. If he was running RHEL it would require symlinking i believe.